# Codeigniter $this->db->get_where

Tags: php, codeigniter

not work submit the form, I have an error.
A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/Admin.php Line Number: 253 Backtrace: File:
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\medicalsystem.com\application\controllers\Admin.php
>   Line: 253 Function: _error_handler
>   Blockquote

```
if ($task == "create"){

    $email = $_POST['email'];       
    $patient = $this->db->get_where('patient', array('email' => $email))->row()->name;      
    if ($patient == null) {
        $this->crud_model->save_patient_info();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', get_phrase('patient_info_saved_successfuly'));
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', get_phrase('duplicate_email'));
    }
    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/patient');
}
```

**Error line code**

```
$patient = $this->db->get_where('patient', array('email' => $email))->row()->name;
```

this line has a problem.

Comment: what is this `->row()->name` remove this `->row()->name` and try again codeigniter `get_where()` want only to parameters NO.1 **TABLE NAME** NO.2 **WHERE Array** you can pass this like it`get_where("table", array("email"=>$email));`

Comment: use this code in your model that code works for me `public function get_where($table, $where)
 {
     $query = $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
     return $query->result_array();
 }`

Comment: what is get_phrase

Comment: show your controller

Comment: and where save_patient_info() method is

Comment: ur here only getting data where is insertion

Comment: function save_patient_info()
    {
        $data['name']   = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['email']   = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['password']       = sha1($this->input->post('password'));
        $data['address']  = $this->input->post('address');
        $data['phone']          = $this->input->post('phone');
        $data['sex']            = $this->input->post('sex');
        $data['birth_date']     = strtotime($this->input->post('birth_date'));
        $data['age']            = $this->input->post('age');

Comment: $data['blood_group']  = $this->input->post('blood_group');
        
        $this->db->insert('patient',$data);
        
        $patient_id  =   $this->db->insert_id();
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/patient_image/" . $patient_id . '.jpg');
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($task == "create"){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $patient = $this->db->get_where('patient', array('email' => $email))->result_array();

    if ($patient == null) {
        $this->crud_model->save_patient_info();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', get_phrase('patient_info_saved_successfuly'));
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', get_phrase('duplicate_email'));
    }

    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/patient');
}
```

If you want to access patient name then you can access as `$patient['name']`